# Laravel Auth Guard custom attempt always return null

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-7, laravel-authentication

I'm making multiple login with multiple guard.
I have 2 custom guards, admin and investors. When I try login for admin it works. But when it tried to login with investor it won't login and when I check with dd($attempt) it return null.

my custom guards look like this:

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
          ],
  
        'investor' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'investors',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],

        'investors' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Investor::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],

        'investors' => [
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
```

Route web.php :

```
Route::prefix('/investor')->group(function() {
Route::get('/login','Auth\InvestorController@showLoginForm')->name('investor.login');
Route::post('/login', 'Auth\InvestorController@login')->name('investor.login.submit');
Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\InvestorController@logout')->name('investor.logout');

Route::middleware('auth:investor')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/', 'Web\DashboardController@index_investor' )->name('investor.super_dashboard');
    Route::view('forgot_password', 'auth.reset_password')->name('password.reset');
```

Login function for investor :

```
 public function login(Request $request)
    {
      // Validate the form data
      $check =$this->validate($request, [
        'username'   => 'required',
        'password' => 'required|min:6'
      ]);

      $attempt=Auth::guard('investor')->attempt($request->only('username','password'), $request->remember);
      // Attempt to log the user in
      dd(Auth::guard('investor')->user());
      if ($attempt) {
        // if successful, then redirect to their intended location
            return "redirect()->intended(route('investor.super_dashboard'))";  
      } 
      // if unsuccessful, then redirect back to the login with the form data
      return redirect()->intended(route('investor.login'));
    }
```

already tried with :
`$credential = $request->only('username','password')`
`auth('investor')->attempt($credential);`
or
`Auth::guard('investor')->attempt($credential);`

Still not work

Comment: Welcome to so .. `$request->only('username','password')` to `$request->only(['username','password'])` fix this it should be array  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-a-portion-of-the-input-data

Comment: stil didnt work. i already tried with `Auth::guard('investor')->attempt((['username' => $request->username,'password'=>$request->pasword]), $request->remember)`.
and didn't work too

Comment: make sure you store `Hash` password while register

Comment: already stored in database. and it hashed. im so confused right now.

Comment: @KamleshPaul you can pass multiple arguments or an array to `only`